# Is there a BLAS/LAPACK function for calculating Cholesky factor updates?

Tags: fortran, linear-algebra, blas, openblas

Let `A` be a positive definite matrix, and let `A=L*L'` be its cholesky factorization, where `L` is lower triangular.
Let `A2 = A + alpha*x*x'` be a rank-1 update of matrix `A`, where `x` is a vector of appropriate dimension and `alpha` is a scalar.

The [Cholesky factor update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Updating_the_decomposition) is a procedure for obtaining the factorization `A2=L2*L2'` without calculating `A2` first, which is useful to speed up computations in the case of such low-rank matrix updates.

I am using BLAS/LAPACK libraries for elementary algebra manipulations. I can calculate the Cholesky factorization of a positive definite matrix with the routine [spptrf](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/df5/group__real_o_t_h_e_rcomputational_ga2bea5d870e14f7656183aed657af355d.html#ga2bea5d870e14f7656183aed657af355d). However, I have been looking around and I have not been able to find a BLAS/LAPACK function which performs Cholesky factor updates. May it be that there is not function doing so?

**Additionally:** In this [old post](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2646), the addition of such routine was discussed. However, it is a very old post (2013) and I have not been able of finding anything more recent.

Comment: Note that, I quote, *"Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 2):

There is no such function. You can look at this discussion we had on SciPy. I've made up a Python script that does the update with the relevant paper. You can make use of those information.

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8188

If you feel competitive and actually write the Fortran code for this, I would really appreciate if you can submit it to LAPACK repo as a PR https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack

Answer (score 1):

The BLAS libraries on Netlib as you pointed out however I doubt it is on the site. If you are looking for code simply there is code [here.](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8294-arbitrary-rank-update-to-cholesky-factorization) 
If you want it fast I'd just turn that code into Julia. There is a book I've never checked out which may have these in [it.](https://www.mathworks.com/support/books/book119252.html) Also, note you cited a paper that the author wrote the code for. You could have simply contacted the author of the paper. His website appears to be [here.](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/) There is a problem with that link though.